# "java.net.ConnectException: null" for no apparent reason after some changes

Tags: java, api, exception, oauth-2.0, properties

I am connecting to an oAuth server to get the security Token in order to access a API I'm using. At first I had the following class, with the parameters hard-coded:

```
public class TermineApiClient {
public static final String TOKEN_URI = "https://testapi.de/oauth/v2/token";
public static final String API_URL = "https://testapi.de/clients/2/events?startDate=2021-04-30";
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "5544zj80ghcs0o8g";
public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "5pp5dn48k9s";
public static final String GRANT_TYPE = "client_credentials";
```

Then I called the server with the following function and it was all working just fine:

```
    public static String getToken() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(TOKEN_URI))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&grant_type=" + GRANT_TYPE))
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    //bind response to Authentication object
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(response.body(), Authentication.class).getAccess_token();
}
```

But since I don't want my parameters hard-coded I made some changes to the class to get them from the **application.yml** file, leaving the class like that:

```
@Component
public class TermineApiClient {
public static String TOKEN_URI;
public static String API_URL;
public static String CLIENT_ID;
public static String CLIENT_SECRET;
public static String GRANT_TYPE;

@Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
public void setTokenUri(String accessTokenUri){
    TermineApiClient.TOKEN_URI = accessTokenUri;
}
@Value("${application.termineRegional.baseUrl}")
public void setApiUrl(String apiUrl){
    TermineApiClient.API_URL = apiUrl;
}
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
public void setClientId(String clientId){
    TermineApiClient.CLIENT_ID = clientId;
}
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret){
    TermineApiClient.CLIENT_SECRET = clientSecret;
}
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.grantType}")
public void setGrantType(String grantType){
    TermineApiClient.GRANT_TYPE = grantType;
}
```

And it's weird that now it simply doesn't work anymore, even though there is no problem in getting the parameters. Whenever it gets to this line `HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());` it throws a **ConnectException: null**

Stacktrace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: null
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:571) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123) ~[java.net.http:na]
at com.events.termineapi.Client.TermineApiClient.getToken(TermineApiClient.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
at com.events.termineapi.Client.TermineApiClient.getEvents(TermineApiClient.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
at com.events.termineapi.Controller.EventsController.getEvents(EventsController.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: null
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.toConnectException(Utils.java:1045) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:198) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.AsyncSSLConnection.connectAsync(AsyncSSLConnection.java:56) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.createAsync(Http2Connection.java:378) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2ClientImpl.getConnectionFor(Http2ClientImpl.java:128) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ExchangeImpl.get(ExchangeImpl.java:93) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.establishExchange(Exchange.java:343) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsyncImpl0(Exchange.java:475) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsyncImpl(Exchange.java:380) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsync(Exchange.java:372) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsyncImpl(MultiExchange.java:408) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl$7(MultiExchange.java:449) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandleStage(CompletableFuture.java:950) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:2340) ~[na:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsyncImpl(MultiExchange.java:439) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsync0$2(MultiExchange.java:341) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1773) ~[na:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:155) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2673) ~[na:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsync(MultiExchange.java:294) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.sendAsync(HttpClientImpl.java:652) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:550) ~[java.net.http:na]
... 52 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:149) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:157) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkRemote(SocketChannelImpl.java:816) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:839) ~[na:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$connectAsync$0(PlainHttpConnection.java:183) ~[java.net.http:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[na:na]
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:185) ~[java.net.http:na]
... 75 common frames omitted
```

**Please, could anyone help me? It looks like such a silly problem, and I'm stuck. Thanks!!!**

**EDIT:**

Here's the .yml file and changed the static properties to non-static

```
application:
  termineRegional:
    baseUrl: https://testapi.de/clients/2/events?startDate=2021-04-30

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      grantType: client_credentials
      clientId: 5544zj80ghcs0
      clientSecret: 5pp5dn48
      accessTokenUri: https://testapi.de/oauth/v2/token

spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude[0]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
    exclude[1]: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

@Component
public class TermineApiClient {

```
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
private String TOKEN_URI;
@Value("${application.termineRegional.baseUrl}")
private String API_URL;
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
private String CLIENT_ID;
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
private String CLIENT_SECRET;
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.grantType}")
private String GRANT_TYPE;

public List<Event> getEvents() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String token = getToken();
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(API_URL))
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return mapper.readValue(response.body(), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Event.class));
}

public String getToken() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(TOKEN_URI))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&grant_type=" + GRANT_TYPE))
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    //bind response to Authentication object
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(response.body(), Authentication.class).getAccess_token();
}
```

Comment: looks like the setters are not getting injected. Why do you need a setter to initialise the values from yml file. A simple @Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
String accessTokenUri ; should work, or else you would need to create a @Bean

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I put a breakpoint and checked, the values were injected correctly, they are there. I used the setters because the properties are "static" and SpringBoot doesn't let the values to be injected directly. Before I did that there was another problem where it was trying to access the values and they were null.

Comment: Why do you want to have the values as static, when you are reading them from yml, what is the advantage you are getting

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I tried changing everything to non-static and the '@Value' annotation didn't work. I get a null exception when trying to use the values:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.input" is null

Comment: please share you yml, and also the updated java changes

Comment: since we don't have static now, we can do away with setters, and use only @Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}") String accessTokenUri ;

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I tried to, but it didn't work, the values are not injected this way. It returns java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.input" is null